# Remove some items from webview Windows 10 UWP C#

Tags: c#, windows, webview, uwp

How can I remove elements from a webview. I mean, I need to remove sidebar, so is there any way to remove the whole tag of sidebar from HTML? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One practical approach is to use JavaScript injection in one or another way. In particular you can consider using the [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) method to run whatever JavaScript code you want.

```
var script = 'var list = document.querySelectorAll("sidebar"); for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){var e = list[i]; e.parentNode.removeChild(e); }';

await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", script);
```

Comment: Can you please explains in detail?

Comment: As I understand you want to "edit" html-page loaded into a WebView. There are various potential approaches - one of them is to do "editings" via execution of some JavaScript code in the context of that page. InvokeScriptAsync allow to run whatever JS-function with defined arguments. I'm using eval function in that case. JavaScript-code looks for "sidebar" tags and removes them from the DOM.

Comment: "var script = 'var list = document.querySelectorAll("sidebar"); for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){var e = list[i]; e.parentNode.removeChild(e); }';
" gives error.

Answer (score 1):

You can read HTML source, edit it content as you like and use [NavigateToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx) instead of [Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate.aspx)

Comment: This will reload the page instead of edit the current page.